# Does AS3 TweenLITE have an minimum tweenTime limit?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, gsap

I am using tweenLite in a game that I am making

the thing is that it seems to have a mimimum speed alowed, is that so?

the fastest I get it to go is 0.01 seconds,,,  If I set the time lower it just display the tween at the same speed it would do with 0.01

I have tryed really low values and no luck (for example 0.0000001)

help?

best,

Alvaro

---

I seeeeeee now, the limitant was the framerate, tween lite can't go faster than the FPS, I setted the framerate higher and the tween went faster.

Wanna explain why so short tweens,   the thing is this.

I am making a little game, and I am programin the character walk cycle.

I have the character composed with body parts, legs arms foots etc,

So my walk function have 4 stages (Rleg.rotation = 22, Rleg.rotation = 0, Rleg.rotation = -22, Rleg.rotation=0)

But each of those 4 stages is then divided in 10 tweens,  You might ask why??????

well, depending on where the character is facing the leg rotation can be:

1) a normal rotation when the character is walking to the side,
2) scaleY transformation when the character is walking towards the camara, and and for example a tween from -45 degrees to 45 degrees in scaleY would be a tween from scaleY = .5 to scaleY = .5  it would not do anything!!!, so that is why I divided the stages in 10 tweens. doing that the scaleY would go something like this:  .5 - .6 - .7 - .8 - .9 - 1 - .9 -.8 -.7 -.5

Comment: .01 = 1/100th of a sec.  Your frame rate is what?  In most cases say 1/30 sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as it's a non negative number any value should work. With values that low, I'm suprised you can really tell that much of a difference in the time past .001. For more proof see here:

http://forums.greensock.com/topic/1630-minimum-time-solved/

Comment: I added some more info to the main text explaining a little more the issue

Answer (score 1):

.01 = 1/100th of a sec.  Your frame rate is what?  In most cases say 1/30 sec.  So in this case it's irrelevant to even have a tween if the display can't show a difference.  Since tweens are supposed to span  more than one frame - there can be no iteration or steps in 1/100th of a second or even 1/30th.